# First assign and then reassign in if block as alternative to if-(else if)-else in Verilog

Tags: logic, verilog, hardware, hdl

Is it better to first assign a value to a variable and then reassign in if block instead of using if-(else if)-else blocks where the assignment in if and else blocks are the same and the assignment in the else if block is a different assignment.

```
always @(*) begin
    if condition1 begin
        var = val1;
    end
    else if condition2 begin
        var = val2;
    end
    else begin
        var = val1;
    end
end
```

vs

```
always @(*) begin
    var = val1;
    if condition2 begin
        var = val2;
    end
end
```

Given condition1 and condition2 are mutually exclusive, I am thinking that both of these blocks should synthesize the same logic and the choice of one over the other is purely aesthetic. Am I correct in thinking this or will one implementation synthesize differently from the other? If my thinking is correct, which method is preferred in the community?

Edit: Added mutually exclusive criteria after racraman's comment.

Comment: The two code blocks are not the same;  If both condition1 and condition2 are true, the first returns val1 but the second returns val2.

Comment: You are right. What about if condition1 and condition2 are mutually exclusive? Would they synthesize the same in that case?

Comment: Yes a or change the second code block to “if condition2 && ! condition1”.   Btw, my preference is for the second, so might write an answer shortly :)

Comment: how does synthesis know that the condition is mutually exclusive? In your case different logic will be synthesized. But case 2 will be the same as `if(condition2) var=val2; else var = val1;`

Comment: is there any reason why something like ```var = !condition1 && condition2 ? val2 : val1;``` (as alternative for the first example) or ```var =  condition2 ? val2 : val1;``` (for the second) is not considered? Cus in the end it will be some kind of multiplexer anyway and this way one can "see" it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the general principle you're asking about: it doesn't matter which route you go. The synthesiser will be smart enough to work it out anyway. For simulation, it's possible that the option which carries out a default assignment first might execute more slowly (particularly if the assignment is a non-blocking one), but I wouldn't worry about it.

Personally, I prefer the second, because it's more obvious to the causual reader that you have covered your bases in terms of generating unwanted latches (in other words, you are always assigning to `var`).

Having said all that, your example is (in principle) very simple, and in this particular case it's obvious that a mux is required, and you probably don't need an always block at all, and should just use an `assign` with a ternary operator.

I say 'in principle' because you logic doesn't really make sense. You say your conditions are mutually exclusive, but what happens if neither condition is active? Do you actually need a latch to *preserve* the previous output? If not, why do you have two conditions at all?

Comment: How would it change if instead of `always @(*)` I had `always @(posedge clk)`? I won't be able to use assign in the same manner as you described. Would I still be better off using method 2 instead of method 1 to avoid inferred flip-flops while keeping the code clean and easy-to-understand?

Comment: There's no possibility of inferred latches with `posedege clk`, so there's no issue - everything is different. I think you need to go back and draw a timing diagram, or a circuit diagram, of exactly what you want, and decide whether it has to be clocked or not.

Comment: I solved my original problem with the `assign` statement. However I had a brain-wave (uncommon for me) regarding what would happen if I had a clocked design and could risk inferring flip-flops if I used method 1 and forgot to cover all if-else conditions vs. using method 2.

Answer (score 0):

While using always@(*) blocks you may end up inferring unintentional latches in your design.
For assignments of the type you have mentioned its better to go for ternary operators.

```
assign var = (cond1)?(val1):(cond2)?(val2):(val1); 
                                 //Assuming cond1 and cond2 are mutually exclusive
```

If cond1 and cond2 can occur at the same time then above assign can be changed as

```
 assign var = (cond1 && cond2)?(val1):(cond1)?(val1):(cond2)?(val2):(val1);
                                //Assuming val1 when both cond1/2 are high
```